# About the continuity of the partial derivative

Tags: multivariable-calculus, continuity, partial-derivative

I'm trying to study if the following function has continuous partial derivatives at the origin:
$$f(x, y) = \begin{cases}\frac{x^4y^3}{x^8 + y^4} & (x, y) \neq (0, 0) \\\\ \quad 0 & (x, y) = (0, 0)\end{cases}$$

I proved $f$ is continuous at the origin, and I also proved its partial derivatives exist at the origin.

Now to show the continuity of $f'_x$ at $(0, 0)$ here is what I did:

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = \frac{4x^3y^3(y^4 - x^8)}{(x^8 + y^4)^2}$$

Having observed it goes to zero along various paths, I did:

$$\bigg|\frac{4x^3y^3(y^4 - x^8)}{(x^8 + y^4)^2}\bigg| \leq \frac{4x^2y^2|x| |y| (x^8 + y^4)}{(x^8+y^4)^2} \leq \frac{4x^2y^2|x| |y|}{y^4} = \frac{4x^2|x|}{|y|}$$

But now I am stuck.

If for example I say $y = x^4$, this reduces to $\frac{4}{|x|}$ which does not goes to zero.

But the notes say the partial derivatives are continuous (without any proof...)

Any help? Thank you!

**Notice** We cannot use polar coordinates. We are demanded to find a distance function to make an upper bound to the function we have, in order to conclude it goes to $0$ as $(x, y) \to (0, 0)$.

Comment: you need a better upper bound... The fact that your upper bound goes to infinity says nothing about the behaviour of the functions you are trying to bound.

Comment: @PierreCarre Any help with that, considering I'm not allowed to use polars? :/

Answer (score 4):

In problems like this I find it useful to use a homogenized form of polar coordinates: Let $x^4=r\cos\theta$ and $y^2=r\sin\theta$, with $0\le\theta\le\pi/2$. Then
$$\left|\frac{x^3y^3(y^4-x^8)}{(y^4+x^8)^2}\right| = \frac{r^{3/4}r^{3/2}r^2|\cos 2\theta||\cos\theta|^{3/4}|\sin\theta|^{3/2}}{r^4} \le r^{3/4+3/2-2} = r^{1/4}.$$
You still have to do a little bit of algebraic work to finish. How do we bound $r^{1/4}$ by a power of $(x^2+y^2)^{1/2}$?

**EDIT**: $r^2=x^8+y^4\le x^4+y^4\le (x^2+y^2)^2$ when $x^2+y^2\le 1$.

Comment: I forgot to say we cannot use polars. Our professor didn't teach them to us because "it's too mechanical" and we have to use $\leq$...

Comment: Well, I agree that many people on this site abuse the technique, but the clever homogenization here is powerful and is not the "usual" mechanical approach at all. Your professor must love algebraic contortions with the AMGM inequality. At any rate, remove the trig and use $x^4=u$, $y^2=v$ and work harder.

Comment: AMGM we use it! I also tried with AMGM from the very beginning (after passing from $y^4 - x^8$ to $x^4 +y^8$ but what I get is $$\frac{2|y|}{|x|}$$ and the problem remains...

Comment: And this is what I don't get, because if I take $x = y^6$ then as $y \to 0$ I don't get a finite result.

Comment: I'm not a fan of AMGM contortions, so I'm going to let you ignore my solution if you insist. My approach does show the sensitivity of the question to each and every exponent that appears. One of my favorite problems to assign to my students was to determine for precisely which values of $\alpha,\beta,\gamma,\delta$ the function $|x|^\alpha|y|^\beta/(|x|^\gamma+|y|^\delta)$ (and $0$ at $0$) is continuous/differentiable. Good luck.

Comment: Yes, I'll work on that if and when I will have understood this one, for which your solution I cannot take, and my doubts are not solved.

Comment: Throwing away terms, as you insist on doing, in the denominator is not going to work with these subtle functions.

Comment: I understand, but this is THE ONLY WAY we can do this exercise. Majorizations in order to bound it with a distance (Euclidean one, for example, or multiples of it)

Comment: @MartinandFriends there is no problem with the path $x=y^6$, you still get zero as a limit.

Comment: @PierreCarre Sorry but how can I get $0$, since it becomes $\frac{2|y|}{y^6} = \frac{2}{|y^5|}$, and as $y \to 0...$

Comment: @PierreCarre Please can you tell me why the limit still goes to zero?

Comment: @MartinandFriends There is no problem with the path $x = y^6$ in the original function $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$... The problem you are detecting is in the upper bound that you derived, but the upper bound can go to infinity while the partial derivative does not.

Comment: @PierreCarre Ah ok.. Well I am stuck in proving the continuity with the majorisation. Any help for that?

Answer (score 3):

If you really don't like trigonometric functions, we can consider the rectangles instead; however, this is not really any different than Ted Shifrin's answer.

Consider the family of rectangles
$$
\max(x^2,|y|)=r\tag1
$$
On each rectangle,
$$
r^4\le x^8+y^4\le2r^4\tag2
$$
and for $r\le1$, $\mathrm{d}((x,y),(0,0))\ge r$.

Thus, we have
$$
\begin{align}
|f_x(x,y)|
&=\left|\frac{4x^3y^3\left(y^4-x^8\right)}{\left(x^8+y^4\right)^2}\right|\tag{3a}\\
&\le\frac{4r^{3/2}r^3r^4}{r^8}\tag{3b}\\[9pt]
&=4r^{1/2}\tag{3c}\\[12pt]
&\le4\mathrm{d}((x,y),(0,0))^{1/2}\tag{3d}
\end{align}
$$
So we can choose a rectangle small enough so that $f_x(x,y)$ is as small as we wish.

---

However, on the path $(x,y)=\left(r^{1/2},r\right)$,
$$
\begin{align}
|f_y(x,y)|
&=\left|\frac{x^4y^2\left(3x^8-y^4\right)}{\left(x^8+y^4\right)^2}\right|\tag{4a}\\
&=\frac{r^2r^2(2r^4)}{4r^8}\tag{4b}\\[9pt]
&=\frac12\tag{4c}
\end{align}
$$
Whereas, along the path $(x,y)=(0,r)$, $f_y(x,y)=0$. That is, $f_y$ cannot be defined at $(0,0)$ so as to make $f_y$ continuous.

Comment: It's not that I don't like trigonometric. It's that out professor demand us to use "$\leq$ things" that is, we have to upper bound functions with a distance function (possibly the Euclidean one), so I thank you too but unfortunately I cannot use what you wrote

Comment: Anyway, does your method prove the derivative is NOT continuous?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by the "$\le$ things". Both Ted and I give bounds for $|f_x|$ using $\le$.

Comment: "that is, we have to upper bound function with a distance function". So it should end like
$$|f(x, y) - f(0, 0)| \leq d(x, y)$$
Where $d$ is a distance function.

Comment: In both our answers, $f_x(0,0)=0$; that is shown by the estimates given. If you need to, you can replace $|f_x(x,y)|$ with $|f_x(x,y)-0|$.

Comment: I got this, but your answers, which are great, are not what I asked for, that is
$$|f'_x(x, y)| \leq k d(x, y)$$
Where $d$ is the Euclidean distance and $k\in\mathbb{R}$

Comment: There is no constant $k$ so that that is true because the lower bound varies as $\mathrm{d}(x,y)^{1/2}$

Comment: Then this problem should be impossible, which is not. There must be a way to bound that function with a distance. I don't care if it's $4\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ or $190(x^2+y^2)^{1/8}$, both are good to me. What I asked for was this: an upper bound with a distance function

Comment: It can be bounded by the square root of the distance, but not $k\mathrm{d}(x,y)$.

Comment: That would be perfect! Perhaps I expressed myself bad. "A function of a distance" maybe? I mean something of the general form $k (x^2+y^2)^a$ where $a > 0$ and $k> 0$ (but $k$ is not really interesting for "my" purposes)

Comment: @MartinandFriends Notice the last sentence of my post. That part is elementary if you start, say, with $x^2+y^2\le 1$.

Comment: @TedShifrin One more hint? I tried to manipulate but I am still in deep waters :/

Comment: See my edit. ….

Answer (score 1):

As Ted and Rob already pointed out, summing their hints let me see if I can convince you.
Notice that: $x^3 = (x^8)^{3/8} \leq (x^8 + y^4)^{3/8}$ and $y^3 = (y^4)^{3/4} \leq (y^4 + x^8)^{3/4}$. We can then write:

$$\bigg|\frac{4x^3y^3(y^4-x^8)}{(x^8 + y^4)^2}\bigg| \leq \frac{4(x^8+y^4)^{3/8} (x^8 + y^4)^{3/4} (x^8+y^4)}{(x^8 + y^4)^2} = 4(x^8 + y^4)^{3/8 + 3/4 + 1 - 2} = 4(x^8+y^4)^{1/8}$$

Which goes to $0$ as $(x, y) \to (0, 0)$.

Comment: That was indeed clear! Thanks.